# Exclude and Include column header based on condition in Select statement in Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, oracle, select, pivot, union

I have a table with schema as below

```
Documentno  created      docstatus
498461      08-OCT-14    IN
501681      27-OCT-14    IN
544491      19-AUG-15    IP
550041      28-SEP-15    IP
```

Output should be in format like

```
select Documentno, created from c_order where docstatus in ('IP')
Documentno  created      
544491      19-AUG-15    
550041      28-SEP-15    

select Documentno, created,docstatus from c_order where docstatus in ('IN')
Documentno  created      docstatus
498461      08-OCT-14    IN
501681      27-OCT-14    IN
```

Expected Output like union

```
  Documentno     created      
    544491      19-AUG-15    
    550041      28-SEP-15   
  Documentno   created       docStatus
    498461      08-OCT-14    IN
    501681      27-OCT-14    IN
```

Is this possible in sql select statement?
I have tried with Case but it works only for Value not for column name
Please any one guide me how to implement this select statement in oracle?

Answer (score 0):

You must give column name at least it should consist of one character

Test data

```
with t(Documentno,
created,
docstatus) as
 (select 498461, sysdate, 'IN'
    from dual
  union all
  select 501681, sysdate + 1, 'IN'
    from dual
  union all
  select 544491, sysdate + 2, 'IP'
    from dual
  union all
  select 550041, sysdate + 3, 'IP'
    from dual)
```

Query

```
  select Documentno, created, null as " "
      from t
     where docstatus in ('IP')
    union all
    select null, null, 'STATUS'
      from dual
    union all
    select Documentno, created, docstatus from t where docstatus in ('IN')
```

Output

```
DOCUMENTNO CREATED
---------- -------- ------
    544491 10/07/16
    550041 11/07/16
                    STATUS
    498461 08/07/16 IN
    501681 09/07/16 IN
```